# Integrating python-docx with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have installed the newest `QGIS` and downloaded `python-doc`x from this link [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html#install) . I haven't installed separately a different version of python. Is it possible to integrate this package of python-docx to work with QGIS (Windows version) ?

1. I looked at this site [Installing Third-party Python Modules in QGIS (Windows)](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2016/03/02/installing-third-party-python-modules-in-qgis-windows/)
2. After changing this section `call(['easy_install', 'lxml'])` to `call(['easy_install', 'python-docx'])` and run code in QGIS Python console I've got an error
   :
   [image]

Comment: Did you know how to install a Python module ?

Comment: I did it on Virtual machine with portable python (and it works but only with python console). I don't know how to install this python module with QGIS.

Comment: There are many answers in GIS SE, look for example in  [QGIS docutils install (path,pythonpath,pythonhome)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181367/2581)

Comment: @gene I update my question. The problem is still not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

To install this python module or any other you can follow this flow.

1. Create a .bat (py3_qgis.bat) with this lines, (change your **QGIS 3** path)

   ```
   @ECHO OFF 

   :: QGIS path
   set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64 

   set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
   set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin

   @echo off
   call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat
   call qt5_env.bat
   call py3_env.bat
   @echo off
   path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%

   cd /d %~dp0

   start cmd
   ```
2. In the cmd opened by the previous script, write this:

   ```
   python3 -m pip install python-docx
   ```
3. Open QGIS and import the module:

   ```
   from docx import Document
   ```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should use the following code, in osgeo shell(just check python 2.7 is not your default python in shell), or from pycharm terminal(after configuring pycharm to know your qgis 3 python following [Setting up PyCharm for PyQGIS and Qt](https://nathanw.net/2014/05/10/setting-up-pycharm-for-pyqgis-and-qt/))

```
python3 -m pip install python-docx
```

just notice that the qgis 3 python console intellisense will not be updated, but in pycharm, yes, how ever the module import works for both.